# How to disable flycheck warning while editing emacs lisp scripts?

Tags: emacs, flycheck

I am now engaged with emacs prelude and find everything nice. But

> A lot of flycheck warnings are displayed while editing el file
>
> and syntax coloring is  overrided

Warnings like "the first line shoud be of form package --- summary"

> How to turn off those warnings?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

These are Checkdoc warnings.  To disable these, add `emacs-lisp-checkdoc` to the option `flycheck-disabled-checkers`, either with the following code in your init file

```
(with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
  (setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(emacs-lisp-checkdoc)))
```

or via the customize interface with `M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-disabled-checkers`.

Comment: thanks guy! Checkdoc seems too much for me. That's what i am looking for

Comment: Hi, how can I delete multi checkers from flycheck-checkers?

Comment: @goofansu Uhm, well, just do the above for each checker you want to remove?!  Or use customize and untick all these checkers, if you don't know Emacs Lisp.

Comment: @lunaryorn Thank you. I'll customize it.

Comment: @goofansu Please note, that starting with the upcoming Flycheck 0.16 (or the latest MELPA packages), you should reset `flycheck-checkers` to its standard value and customize `flycheck-disabled-checkers` instead.  See the updated answer for details.

Comment: The second expression is missing a quote: (eval-after-load 'flycheck '(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(emacs-lisp-checkdoc)))

Comment: @Hugo Thanks.  I updated the answer to use `with-eval-after-load`, and also removed all outdated information about `flycheck-checkers`.

Comment: Does it also covers `.emacs` file?

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to disable a particular Flycheck just for this one file, you can also use a file-local variable definition.

You can do this interactively while in the file's buffer by typing

```
  M-x add-file-local-variable flycheck-disabled-checkers RET
  (emacs-lisp-checkdoc)
```

which will add a local variables section to the end of the file.

```
;; Local Variables:
;; flycheck-disabled-checkers: (emacs-lisp-checkdoc)
;; End:
```

This is like customizing `flycheck-disabled-checkers` but only for the file.

This can also be customized on the level of the directory. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Directory-Variables